# One Producer Multiple Consumers for one state Object

Tags: java, java-8, locking, synchronized, producer-consumer

I have one producer that:

```
maintains ref StateRef to object StateObj
implements method modify() method which modifies StateObj
implements getRef() method which will be used by consumers
```

I have multiple consumers which get ref to StateObj and read StateObj

(Producer: Modifies stateObj and consumers reads(only) stateObj)

So in typical design I need read-lock by consumers and write-lock by Producer which could be in-efficient.

But since there is only one writer, I have written modify() method as:

```
1. Ref refToCloneCopy = StateRef.clone()
2. update(refToCloneCopy)
3. StateRef = refToCloneCopy
```

Advantage: I don't have to enforce read-lock on consumers.

I want to ensure that till 3rd step is not completed "getRef()" will continue returning ref to StateObj and after step-3 "getRef" will return ref to newState/ClonedObj

There is no requirement of race conditions or consistency i.e. its OK if half consumers receive ref to oldState and other half consumers receive ref to newState(clonedObj). But getRef should not return some weird ref value, it should return either oldState or new State.

I am using Java8 for this. ... Whats best way to handle this efficiently without too much(or NO) locking on consumer side or producer side?

UPDATE:
Even If we decide to take lock in 3rd step above, I want to make sure that lock request by writer/producer should be high priority over lock request by consumers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are guaranteed that it is ok to return the old state while the new state is being created, then you can simply do the cloning and modification as a method level variable and assign it to the stateRef field at the end of that method. It seems like what you mentioned having in modify should fit the bill. One thing to be sure of, though, is to declare stateRef as volatile. Something like this:

```
class Producer {

    private volatile StateObj stateRef;

    StateObj getRef() {
        return stateRef;
    }

    void modify() {
        // Leave the instance field alone until modification is done
        StateObj newObj = (StateObj) stateRef.clone();
        // Do stuff to the new local variable reference. If any consumers
        // call getRef while this is happening they get the stateRef value and
        // not the newObj value.

        // Once the newObj instance if fully initialized, set it as
        // the stateRef instance.
        stateRef = newObj;
    }
}
```

You won't have any producer consumer conflicts with the value since the stateRef is only altered at the very end of the modify method and it is simply set to the new, already fully initialized StateObj instance. Note that the volative keyword is important since otherwise other consumer threads could cache the value of stateRef and not see the change from the producer thread. It also guards against the compiler reordering code.

Comment: But do I need to take lock at last stmt of stateref=newobj as this is not atomic operation when address value in stateref is changing

Comment: Or is ref assignment in Java atomic ?

Comment: @sameer the assignment should be fine. Where volatile isn't enough if get and set need to be atomic. For example if you were to do something like check if stateRef is null and set it only in that case in modify then you would need either synchronized or an AtomicReference. But in your stated use case volatile will be enough.